# My tflite model give totally wrong predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, yolov5

I'm trying to convert a YOLOv5 model to a TFLite model for mobile devices, but I'm having issues with the generated file. The TFLite model is so large in size and is giving completely wrong predictions compared to the original YOLOv5 model.
the original YOLOv5s file is ~13.7 while the TFLite model is ~26.9,
I converted it as follows:

```
!python export.py --weights best.pt --include tflite --img 640 --data data.yaml
```

and then:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('best_saved_model')
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Can anyone provide guidance on how to convert a YOLOv5 model to TFLite properly and ensure that the predictions are accurate? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Fatema. Did you get a solution to this? My model is also giving wrong results when I convert it to tflite

Comment: @AndrewSithole unfortunately no, but while searching i found this if it may be of use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68722909/yolov4-to-tflite-model-giving-completely-wrong-predictions